# Update or modify files owned by root from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, security, server, filesystems, root

I plan to create a web interface to configure a part of my system, including some files owned by root. I will be a NodeJS server and I know that running it as root is not a good idea.

Any suggestions about how to perform that without performance and security issues?

Thank you.

Comment: Vanilla linux do not allow that level of granularity. I believe SELinux will give you that ability. You should look on [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a specific script that will be owned by root with high restricted rights and allow a sudo on that script for a dedicated user without password so that could not log in (only root can do a su on it). 
In the script i will perform wanted action (updte, upgrade, files copy, etc.)

Let's hope that scurity is good enought